# Use the yield to defer Azure blob storage call - c#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, ienumerable, yield

I currently have a method where I pull a list of blob file names from Azure.  The method is as follows:

```
internal async Task<IEnumerable<BlobItem>> GetFiles(CloudBlobContainer container, string directoryName, bool recursive)
{
    var results = new List<BlobItem>();
    BlobContinuationToken continuationToken = null;

    do
    {
        var response = await container.GetDirectoryReference(directoryName).ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(false, BlobListingDetails.None, 100, continuationToken, null, null);

        continuationToken = response.ContinuationToken;
        foreach (var item in response.Results)
        {
            if (item.GetType() != typeof(CloudBlobDirectory))
                results.Add(new BlobItem(item));
            else if (recursive)
                results.AddRange(await GetFiles(container, ((CloudBlobDirectory)item).Prefix, recursive));
        }
    }
    while (continuationToken != null);

    return results;
}
```

What I don't like about my code above is that I run through all files and add to the results until the cancellation token is null.  So basically, go get all, then stop and return.

I don't think this is overly efficient - I was thinking I could maybe yield the results so it only goes and gets the next "batch" of results when I'm ready for it (from the calling code).

I'm not that familiar with using yield and have come up with this but I think it might not be deferring the call to ListBlobSegment.  Here's my code:

```
internal IEnumerable<BlobItem> GetFiles(CloudBlobContainer container, string directoryName, bool recursive)
{
    var results = new List<BlobItem>();
    BlobContinuationToken continuationToken = null;

    do
    {
        var response = container.GetDirectoryReference(directoryName).ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(false, BlobListingDetails.None, 100, continuationToken, null, null).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        continuationToken = response.ContinuationToken;
        foreach (var item in response.Results)
        {


            if (item.GetType() != typeof(CloudBlobDirectory))
                yield return new BlobItem(item);
            else if (recursive)
            {
                var internalResponse =  GetFiles(container, ((CloudBlobDirectory)item).Prefix, recursive));
                foreach (var intItem in internalResponse)
                {
                    yield return intItem;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    while (continuationToken != null);
}
```

could someone advise me if I'm using the `yield` statement in the correct way?  As mentioned, never used this in anger before and want to get it right :-)  My aim to hopefully defer the service call and make the code more efficient for the call.

Thanks in advance for any pointers!

NOTE: using these API's for blob storage

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
```

Comment: weirdly, execution time increased significantly from 1 min 24 seconds (without yield) to 4 minutes 14 seconds with the yield approach - suppose that makes as it's deferring things until when its needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit 2018-11-15**
Starting with **C#8**, you will be able to use `IAsyncEnumerable`:

```
async IAsyncEnumerable<int> GetBigResultsAsync()
{
    await foreach (var result in GetResultsAsync())
    {
        if (result > 20) yield return result; 
    }
}

IAsyncEnumerable<string> GetAsyncAnswers()
{
    return AsyncEnum.Enumerate<string>(async consumer =>
    {
        foreach (var question in GetQuestions())
        {
            string theAnswer = await answeringService.GetAnswer(question);
            await consumer.YieldAsync(theAnswer);
        }
    });
}
```

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/11/12/building-c-8-0/

https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=asyncenum

**Original Answer**

You need to use `IObservable<BlobItem>` instead of `IEnumerable<BlobItem>` in this case. At least internally, depending on how you actually call `GetFiles`.

This question has some great explanation which you should look into:

[How to yield return item when doing Task.WhenAny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18284169/how-to-yield-return-item-when-doing-task-whenany/)

Or the [corresponding blog post](https://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2013/11/29/async-yield-return) for the accepted answer.

Side note: You might want to use the parameter `useFlatBlobListing=true` for `ListBlobsSegmentedAsync` instead of manually doing the recursive code.

Some quick code which describes how this might look (not tested or anything)

```
public IEnumerable<BlobItem> GetFilesAsEnumerable(CloudBlobContainer container, string directoryName, bool recursive)
{
    return GetFiles(container, directoryName, recursive).ToEnumerable();
}

public IObservable<BlobItem> GetFiles(CloudBlobContainer container, string directoryName, bool recursive)
{
    return Observable.Create<BlobItem>(async obs =>
        {
            BlobContinuationToken continuationToken = null;

            do
            {
                var response = await container.GetDirectoryReference(directoryName).ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(/*useFlatBlobListing*/ recursive, BlobListingDetails.None, 100, continuationToken, null, null);

                continuationToken = response.ContinuationToken;
                foreach (var item in response.Results)
                {
                    // Only required if recursive == false
                    if (item.GetType() != typeof(CloudBlobDirectory))
                        obs.OnNext(new BlobItem(item));
                }
            }
            while (continuationToken != null);
        });
}
```

Comment: This is an awesome answer!! +1 Thank you very much Alex!!!  I have the option now to use the "ToEnumerable" or subscribing directly to the "GetFiles" (observable).  Brill!!